# jquery mobile collapsible foreach and event binding caused the collapsible does not expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Hy
I use knockoutjs and jquery mobile. I want to bind collapsible to array, and then use via template. When I bind the event, I can not open the collapsible anymore. The problem is the foreach binding and the event binding. Does not like each other. How can I foreach collapsible, refresh them and use the click event that the collapsible still work. Now I can not open the collapsible

Why? Can anyone fix this code?

```
<script src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>

<section id="page-main" data-role="page" data-fullscreen="true">
            <header data-role="header">
                <h1>Főoldal</h1>
            </header>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-bind="template: {name: 'tmpl', foreach: alma}"}>

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>

<script type="text/html" id="tmpl">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-bind="event: {expand: $root.fooFunc}"> <!-- it is gonna work if you delete the event binding -->
            <h3 data-bind="text: a"></h3>
            <p>
            I'm the collapsible set content for section 1.
            </p>
            </div>
        </script>

    $(function() {
                // Init
                function fooClass() {
                    var self = this;
                    self.alma = ko.observableArray();
                    self.fooFunc = function(){console.log("fired");};
                }

                a = new fooClass();

            a.alma.push({a:"a"});
            a.alma.push({a:"b"});
            a.alma.push({a:"c"});

            ko.applyBindings(a);

            $("[data-role=collapsible-set]").collapsibleset( "refresh" );        

            });




  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/erbsaag/H6SNg/3/
```

Comment: Please add the code from jsfiddle into the your question! Because your question should stand its own without any external source. So  if jsfiddle will go down in the future people still could find and understand your question. Also don't delete and repost the same question ([10k only link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964406/knockout-js-jquery-mobile-collapsible-event-binding-caused-the-code-went-wrong)) if you don't get an answer, this is not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: I just refreshed my question. I copy the code into the question.